# Hibernate throwing error in One-to-one relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, joincolumn

I am trying to implement a one-to-one mapping and below is the entities involved:

## UserID   which acts as composite primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserID  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int ssnID;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

## Vehicle Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    private int vehicleID;
    private String description;
    // getters and  setters..
}
```

## UserInfo entity which has UserID as composite primary key and having one-to-one relationship with Vehicle Entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo {
    @EmbeddedId
    UserID userID; // Object which acts as a primary key (composite primary key)
    private String full_name;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID")
    Vehicle veh;
    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

`UserInfo` is the owning-side entity as it has the `FK` (using @JoinColumn) and has `UserID` as composite primary key.

## When I save the `UserInfo` object, the below are the sql logs of the hibernate:

> Hibernate: drop table UserInfo if exists
>
> Hibernate: drop table Vehicle if exists
>
> Hibernate: create table UserInfo (ssnID integer not null, full_name
>   varchar(255), VEHICLE_ID integer, primary key (ssnID))
>
> Hibernate: create table Vehicle (vehicleID integer not null,
>   description varchar(255), primary key (vehicleID))
>
> Hibernate: alter table UserInfo add constraint
>   FK9nx05ha53jhcue5rwks77x0mv foreign key (VEHICLE_ID) references
>   Vehicle

## After this, it throws the exception:

```
ERROR: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9NX05HA53JHCUE5RWKS77X0MV: PUBLIC.USERINFO FOREIGN KEY(VEHICLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.VEHICLE(VEHICLEID) (100)"; SQL statement:
update UserInfo set full_name=?, VEHICLE_ID=? where ssnID=? [23506-190]


Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9NX05HA53JHCUE5RWKS77X0MV: PUBLIC.USERINFO FOREIGN KEY(VEHICLE_ID) 
REFERENCES PUBLIC.VEHICLE(VEHICLEID) (100)"; SQL statement:
update UserInfo set full_name=?, VEHICLE_ID=? where ssnID=? [23506-190]
```

I am not able to understand why this is throwing the exception; I am not inserting any duplicate values.

Is there any issues in my mapping using @OneToOne or @JoinColumn?

Can anyone help me understand this?

## EDIT:

I have created a helper class which does the actual saving, part of the snippet is:

```
public void saveUser(UserInfo userInfo) {
    Session session = null;
    session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(userInfo);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

So, from main() I call this helper method, and save the Entity `UserInfo` (which has the other entity `Vehicle` set).

Please note I am not saving the `Vehicle` entity, does it need to be saved explicit?

Comment: Well, you're trying to update a user which references an unexisting vehicle. You haven't posted the code which throws the exception so... Side note: your composite ID is not composite at all, since it has a single field? Why are you overcomplicating things like that? Why not just use an Integer directly (especially since you apparently failed to implement hashCode and equals in the UserID class, as required)?

Comment: *does it need to be saved explicit*: yes, otherwise it doesn't exist. Unless you set the appropriate cascade option in your mapping.

Comment: @JBNizet: I have added the code which actually saves the `UserInfo` entity. I am setting the `Vehicle` entity in `UserInfo` and my understand is if we save the "main" entity, then all the "contained" entities are saved. Is this the reason the Vehicle is non-existent even though it is set in the `UserInfo` entity (using setter of UserInfo for Vehicle in it).

Comment: *if we save the "main" entity, then all the "contained" entities are saved* no, that's an incorrect assumption. The hibernate user manual is your friend.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks so much , I got it now. I was under wrong assumption that if we set the "contained" entity by setter, it would get saved.